# C : Lvalue required error when assigning to string

Tags: c

I made a simple structure with both integer and char types, I am facing an Lvalue required error when assigning "Structures" to my LE structure string. I don't understand why because that's normally how I would assign a string.

```
#include<stdio>
#include<conio>

struct Lesson{
    int lessonNumber;
    char lessonName[80];
}LE;

main(){

    LE.lessonName = "Structures";
    LE.lessonNumber = 1;


    printf("%s",LE.lessonName);
    printf("%d",LE.lessonNumber);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: You can't assign to an array, only *copy* to it.

Comment: strcpy instead of =

Comment: You don't have a string type here

Comment: or `LE = (struct Lesson){ .lessonName = "Structures", .lessonNumber = 1};`

Comment: Also `#include<stdio>` should be `#include<stdio.h>`

Comment: Your headers a no standard C haeders, and `main` should have a valid prototype and return an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to go about is (If you don't want to call `strcpy`):

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Lesson{
        int lessonNumber;
        char *lessonName;
}LE;

int main(void){

    LE.lessonName = "Structures";
    LE.lessonNumber = 1;

    printf("%s",LE.lessonName);
    printf("%d",LE.lessonNumber);
}
```

Here `lessonName` is a pointer and *not* an array. With the assignment operator here: `LE.lessonName = "Structures"`, you are assigning the address of where the string "Structures" is stored to `LE.lessonName`.

> i don't understand why. because thats normally how i would assign a
>   string

There are a couple of things to keep in mind here. If you declare `lessonName` as an array (as you have done), you should keep in mind that an array is not something you can assign to. What you can assign to is a specific place / index in an array using the `=` operator. Thus you could build your c-string character-by-character or, you could call the `strcpy` function to copy a string character-by-character (including the `\0`) to `lessonName`.

When you use a pointer (`char *lessonName`) and say something like `LE.lessonName = "Structure"`, this piece of string can't be modified. You can't do `LE.lessonName[0] = 'g'`. Of course you could modify `LE.lessonName` to point to some other string later on like `LE.lessonName = "cat";`.